# Cannot create directory hirerachy of source in Qt creator 2.6.1

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm using qtcreator 2.6.1 which came as part of the Qt 5 SDK.

When I select non Qt projects(plain C/C++ projects) it comes with only 2 folders: headers and source that too are logical only.

My files are all in one single folder. The editor seems to have no option of creating new directory(not even logical) for the project.

How can I arrange my .h and .c files in some directory structure using Qt

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to describe your project using qmake script(s). For grouping sources there is `subdirs` pattern.
CMake also works fine with QtCreator and allows you structuring sources.